# initialize a C# class from an excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, initialization

I have a class in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Private mo As omMsg.Message

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Set mo = New omMsg.Message
End Sub

Private Sub mo_OnMessageSend(ByVal status As omMsg.ProcessStatus, ByVal msg As String)
   ProcessComMessage status, msg
End Sub
```

the mo_OnMessageSend is not getting called.

The C# class is as follows:

```
namespace omMsg
{   
public interface IMessage
{
    void sendMessage(Message.ProcessStatus status, string msg);       
    event Message.MessageHandler OnMessageSend;
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Message : IMessage
{
    public enum ProcessStatus { Retrieving, Generating, Error, Complete }

    public delegate void MessageHandler(ProcessStatus status, string msg);
    public event MessageHandler OnMessageSend;

    public void sendMessage(ProcessStatus status, string msg)
    {
        if (OnMessageSend != null)
            OnMessageSend(status, msg);
    }
}
}
```

Please help. Am i doing the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://huntjason.wordpress.com/2005/07/06/com-interop-really-raising-events-handled-by-a-com-sink/

Answer (score 1):

[A Basic Walk Through](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/):

> We’ll start by walking through a very basic example. We’ll get Excel
>   to call a .NET method that takes a string as input (for example “
>   World”) and returns “Hello” concatenated with that input string (so,
>   for example, “Hello World”).
>
> -Create a C# Windows class library project in Visual Studio 2005 called ‘DotNetLibrary’. It doesn’t matter which folder this is in for
>   the purposes of this example.
>
> -To call a method in a class in our library from Excel we need the class to have a default public constructor. Obviously the class also
>   needs to contain any methods we want to call. For this walk through
>   just copy and paste the following code into our default class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DotNetLibrary
{
    public class DotNetClass
    {
        public string DotNetMethod(string input)
        {
            return "Hello " + input;
        }
    }
}
```

> That’s it: if you look at existing articles on the web, or read the
>   MSDN help, you might think you need to use interfaces, or to decorate
>   your class with attributes and GUIDs. However, for a basic interop
>   scenario you don’t need to do this.
>
> -Excel is going to communicate with our library using COM. For Excel to use a COM library there need to be appropriate entries in the
>   registry. Visual Studio can generate those entries for us.
>
> To do this bring up the project properties (double-click ‘Properties’
>   in Solution Explorer). Then: i) On the ‘Application’ tab click the
>   ‘Assembly Information…’ button. In the resulting dialog check the
>   ‘Make assembly COM-visible’ checkbox. Click ‘OK’. ii) On the ‘Build’
>   tab check the ‘Register for COM interop’ checkbox (towards the bottom:
>   you may need to scroll down).
>
> -Build the library.
>
> -Now start Excel and open a new blank workbook. Open the VBA code editor: i) In Excel 2007 this is a little difficult to find. You have
>   to get the Developer tab visible on the Ribbon if it’s not already set
>   up. To do this click the Microsoft Office Button (top left of the
>   screen), then click Excel Options (at the very bottom). Check the
>   ‘Show Developer tab in the Ribbon’ checkbox in the resulting Options
>   dialog. Click OK. This adds ‘Developer’ to the end of the ribbon menu:
>   click this. Then click the ‘Visual Basic’ icon at the left end of the
>   ribbon. ii) In earlier versions of Office (2003, XP, 2000) just go to
>   Tools/Macro/Visual Basic Editor on the menu bar.
>
> -We now need to include a reference to our new library. Select ‘References’ on the Visual Basic Editor’s ‘Tools’ menu. If you scroll
>   down in the resulting dialog you should find that ‘DotNetLibrary’ is
>   in the list. Check the checkbox alongside it and click ‘OK’.
>
> -Now open the code window for Sheet1 (double click Sheet1 in the Project window). Paste the VBA code below into the code window for
>   Sheet1:

```
Private Sub TestDotNetCall() 
Dim testClass As New DotNetClass 
MsgBox testClass.DotNetMethod(“World”) 
End Sub
```

> -Click anywhere in the code you’ve just pasted in and hit ‘F5’ to run the code. You should get a ‘Hello World’ message box.